# Integers of the form $\beta^p\sum_{i=0}^t d_i\beta^{-i}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, integers

Let $\beta \in \mathbb{N}$, with $\beta \ge 2$. Let $t \in \mathbb{Z}$, with $t\ge 0$. Let $x$ be a (strictly) positive integer such that $x \le \beta^{t+1}$.

*How does one prove that*  $$x = \beta^p\sum_{i=0}^t d_i\beta^{-i},$$
*for some* $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ *and* $d_0, \dots, d_t \in \mathbb{N}$*, assuming* $d_0 \neq 0$ *and* $0 \le d_i \le \beta - 1$*?*

*Why the statement is no longer always true if* $x > \beta^{t+1}$*?*

Answer (score 1):

I will do this for $x < \beta^{t+1}$.

I assume you know already that any such $x$ can be written as
$$
x = \sum_{j=0}^{t} e_{j} \beta^{j},
$$
with $0 \le e_{i} < \beta$. Let $p$ be the largest index such that $e_{p} > 0$. Then
$$
x = \beta^{p} \sum_{j=0}^{p} e_{j} \beta^{j - p}
=
\beta^{p} \sum_{i=0}^{t} d_{i} \beta^{-i},
$$
where we have set $i = p - j$, so that and $d_{i} = e_{p-i}$ for $i = 0, \dots, p$, and $d_{i} = 0$ for $i > p$. Note $d_{0} = e_{p} > 0$.

---

As you have formulated it (perhaps you want $p \le t$), the statement can be true for some $x \ge \beta^{t+1}$. It is for instance true for any power of $\beta$. It is false for instance for $x = \sum_{i=0}^{t+1} \beta^{i}$, simply because you have too many summands.

Comment: From your answer, it does not seem clear to me why the assumption $x \le \beta^{t+1}$ is important; could you comment on that?

Comment: My guess is that $p \le t$ is also required, then it makes sense. Is this the case?